# Was that random Orion Girl a spy in Star Trek 2009?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009

In the Star Trek 2009 movie, early on, we see Uhura discover that Kirk has had an intimate moment with an Orion Girl during his time at Starfleet Academy.

But if I recall correctly, the Orion Women all generate a pheremone that makes men fight for their attention, and infiltrate societies by posing as slave girls.

So is this random Orion Girl a spy for the people of Orion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears it was actually the other way around, in that ([according to Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Gaila_%28Orion%29)) Kirk was the one trying to hack into *her* systems:

> According to writers Roberto Orci and Alex Kurtzman, Gaila worked in the computer lab, which is one of the reasons Kirk was interested in her. Kirk became involved with Gaila to gain access to the computer for the Kobayashi Maru simulation. In a scene deleted from the final cut of the film *Star Trek*, Kirk sent Gaila an e-mail which launched a virus into the simulation computer containing his "cheat patch", allowing him to beat the scenario. [[1]](http://darthmojo.wordpress.com/2009/05/14/trek-scribes-speak-complaints-addressed/#more-1201) During Kirk's hearing, Gaila is clearly visible in the audience, with her arms crossed at all times; in the DVD audio commentary for the film, this was stated to be a holdover from the previous scene, as she is quite upset with Kirk for using her in such a way.

Also in that article (and possibly more relevant):

> Screenwriter Roberto Orci said Gaila could have escaped the life of an Orion slave girl because "*there's an underground railroad and some of the Orion slave girls got out and they were sold to freedom.*" [[2]](http://movieblog.ugo.com/movies/roberto-orci-star-trek-interview) This might be seen as contradicting a depiction of Orions established in the *Star Trek: Enterprise* episode "Bound", wherein Orion women use pheromones to manipulate humanoid men.

Comment: Hack into her systems? Is that what we're calling it now?

Comment: So Kirk is using a woman just to cheat on a test? William Shatner's Kirk was a bit of a dick, so Abrams has really outdone himself to make this Kirk so damn unlikable.

Comment: That's certainly a far cry from the original story of Orion 'slave girls', yet I suspect Abrams probably isn't going to delve deeper into why this change took place.

Comment: I don't see a conflict, assuming the pheromones are something that Orion women can turn on and off at will. And just because it's a matriarchal society doesn't mean that ALL females enjoy positions of power. Many of them may actually be slaves.

Answer (score 4):

**No, she was just another of Kirk's sexual conquests. She's probably not a spy for the [Orion Syndicate](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Orion_Syndicate), assuming it even still exists.**

Apparently, in the [Abrams-verse (Star Trek: 2009, Star Trek: Into Darkness)](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Alternate_reality) the people of Orion are [already members of the Federation](http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Orion_%28Star_Trek%29) and training at Star Fleet Academy.

[image]

Comment: As Ro and Nog demonstrate, you don't have to be from a Federation member world to join Starfleet. Unless there's some line I'm forgetting, I think Memory Alpha is getting ahead of itself by suggesting that the Orions in general have joined the Federation in the Abramsverse...

Comment: Do you, by any chance, mean *Into Darkness*?

Comment: @Micah Are you suggesting that some Federation Officer sponsored this Orion girl's entry into the Acadamy? ...I can believe it mind you, I'm just reminding you that is what it takes to get in when your planet's not a member planet.

Comment: @Zibboz: I was just saying we don't know one way or the other (at least based on the movies themselves; according to the other answer it looks like there's some interview-canon I didn't know about).